# glClear and glStencilMask NOT functioning as expected

Tags: c, opengl, glut

In Khronos OpenGL 2.1 Specs they say that glStencilMask should affect the operation of glClear, however, on my machine, this does not seem to be true.

The output I'm currently getting is:

```
Stencil value: (0,0) 0xff
```

The output I'd expect is:

```
Stencil value: (0,0) 0xf0
```

---

Here's my code:

```
void renderScene(void) {
    unsigned char pix;
    int i [4];

    /* Clear the stencil buffer initially */
    glClearStencil(0x0);
    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Applies the following: 1111 0000 & 1111 1111 */
    glStencilMask(0xF0);
    glClearStencil(0xFF);

    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glFlush();

    glReadPixels(0,0,1,1,GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pix);
    printf("Stencil value (0,0): %x\n",pix);
}   

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // init GLUT and create Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_STENCIL );
    glutInitWindowPosition(500,500);
    glutInitWindowSize(320, 320);
    glutCreateWindow("Trial");

    // register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

    // enter GLUT event processing cycle
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

(Obviously I was performing various other drawings etc, but this demonstrates the problem as I see it)

Comment: What is your machine/OS/graphics card? Is the driver up to date?

Comment: How many bits has the stencil buffer, using your visual configuration?

Comment: I'm running Windows XP Professional on a Lenovo 7522P1U, with an intel G41 Express Chipset. And there are 8 stencil bit planes.

Comment: And sorry - after running OpenGL Extensions View 4.04, I have driver version: 6.14.10.5212 - updated 21-Feb-10

Comment: Did you find a cause/workaround? I am having this exact problem in some particular case (ie: Mac OSX 10.7, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, gl version 2.1 ATI-7.18.18). It looks like `glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)` ignore the value of `glStencilMask(the_plane_bit_i_want_to_clear)`, and just clear all bits in the buffer just like we where using `glStencilMask(0xFF)`.

Comment: Unfortunately I never managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs on glReadPixels()

```
GL_STENCIL_INDEX 

Stencil values are read from the stencil buffer.
Each index is converted to fixed point, shifted left or right
depending on the value and sign of GL_INDEX_SHIFT,
and added to GL_INDEX_OFFSET. If GL_MAP_STENCIL is GL_TRUE,
indices are replaced by their mappings in the table GL_PIXEL_MAP_S_TO_S.
```

You might want to check that GL_INDEX_SHIFT and GL_INDEX_OFFSET are both zero by calling

```
glPixelTransferi(GL_INDEX_SHIFT,  0);
glPixelTransferi(GL_INDEX_OFFSET, 0);
```

Maybe you're writing the values correctly, but the glReadPixels scrambles the output. Also try reading more than a single byte:

```
unsigned char pix4[4];
glReadPixels(0,0,1,1,GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pix4);

for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++) printf("Stencil value (0,0,%d): %x\n", i, pix4[i]);
```

Comment: I just tried both, neither made a difference. Interesting about glPixelTransferi though.